# Sending invitations to friends facebook ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk, invite

I'm trying to create in your application, send invitations to your friends from the app facebook. After reading the documentation of Facebook, I was able to get a dialog box with a list of friends and even send the invitation. Confirms a snapshot of the screen.. But invitations to friends not to come because I just can not correctly create a link to the application. Facebook Documentation states that you need to have a link to the current application in AppStote. I found this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK7zh.png) link but I can not understand in what place it is necessary to add to the info plist and how to add the facebook site, so that the request is sent to come and recipients. I spent a lot of time to solve this problem, and all to no avail. Be kind, who faced with this problem, please help me to solve it ... I would be very grateful ...

Friends, I added to the site as the testers

Comment: Ok so you can test that invite friend functionality by adding the one of FB account in Go to Dashboard-> Role->Tester. And after that send the invitation to that person. Bcz to allow invitation to all user you have to submit your app for review on FB developer.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it now, but the problem lies in the fact that I did not set up a URL scheme in the info plist and site facebook.  I tried to do it, I do not even have an example of how to look info plist, but how to add a chart here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/MyApp/?platform=app-links-host

I do not know

Comment: Ok if you have download the FB SDK so in that search the Sample Example as "Scrumptious" in that check there Scrumptious-Info.plist

Comment: Really there an example of SDK facebook in the establishment of URL schemes for sending invites?